# Android Releases in the Google Play Store: Where is the Opt-in URL?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am working to publish a private, internal release for our app in the Google Play Store. I'm getting a message saying "An opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app", but I don't know what else I need to do publish my alpha test apk.

The release status says "full rollout", which indicates to me that everything is done.

I know it takes hours for it to appear but I already waited for days. What do I need to do to get this URL? If I sideload the apk that I created, will it be the same as downloading from the store (in terms of IAP authorisation)?

[image: this sucks]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For many developers, it's just a matter of time. Rolling out merely gets you to the *Pending publication* stage. After some time you reach the *Published* stage and the URL will appear.

However, for your app, it looks like this app in unpublished. You can't opt-in to unpublished apps, so the opt-in link isn't shown.

For questions like this the Developer support team are usually really good, and we do have bugs sometimes, so it is always worth asking them.

Comment: Just had a look. That app is unpublished, and the opt-in link isn't shown for apps that are unpublished. I've modified my answer to reflect this.

Comment: So you need to have published at least one stable version of your app? Or what is the exact meaning of "Published" in the context of Play Store testing?

Comment: The answer by SwiftArchitect ("It's just a matter of time") should be marked as the correct one.

Comment: Actually, no it shouldn't. For this particular developer, they had already waited for days (if you read the question). For this app, the answer was that it was unpublished, which is why it was marked correct. The answer might be "it  is just a matter of time" for other apps, but for the original questioner, this was the correct answer.

Comment: So the "alpha closed" track is unavailable for unpublished apps altogether? This makes little sense as it is forcing me to go to production with my first draft when I'm clearly in need of a closed group of testers.

Comment: @Bilthon I'm with you. We are trying to set up a dev version of our app only for internal testers. It's never meant to go to production. We did it no problem with the iOS version of our app, but Google seems to be preventing us from having a nice, clean workflow.

Comment: @Bilthon, Bryan. You can go to alpha only for the first release of your App. "Unpublished" has a very specific meaning in the play store. It means one which has once been published, and then been removed from the store, so that only existing users can get it. It means "un-published" rather than "not yet published". Of course, for the first version of a new app you can publish as closed track only.

Comment: @BryanDeemer in fact you can use the alpha track for novel apps. It just takes a few days for it to be available for your closed tester group.

Comment: @NickFortescue: Can you please have a look into this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812072/unable-to-retrieve-reminder-details-from-device-calendar

Comment: 'Pending publication' is not shown until you press drop down on very top of the console - it's very confusing and inconvenient. But who cares I guess.

Answer (score 205):

#### It's just a matter of time

1. Rolling out merely gets you to the *Pending publication* stage
   [image: Pending Publication]
2. After some time (say 45 minutes) you will reach the *Published* stage and the **Opt-in URL**
   [image: Published]

Comment: It can sometimes be days. Just thought i'd mention that. (I'm waiting for now just over a day for mine to go to published).

Comment: The first release usually takes more time than subsequent releases. I have waited for a few hours in my worst cases.

Comment: This is great info.  For me it only shows if I press the dropdown.   If not, it doesn't show.

Comment: For those of you wondering why it may take hours.. Google runs a pre-launch report. You can check the status of this report under the release management drop-down navigation

Comment: Just to make it clear: Is that the case for internal testing  track aswell? Or just closed track?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect so publishing means rollout to Alpha or just to internal test is enough? Can you elaborate on "Published" stage. When is it exactly published? Only after rollout to Alpha? or internal test

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it is much more clear than the currently accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: this opt in url could be accessed publicly?

Comment: Long story short even internal testing releases **have to** clear Google Play Store tests, hence the wait time

Comment: Google really needs to change this. iOS is much better for rapid deployment via testflight. I have been waiting 2 days now (which is an eternity on our schedule) just to get an alpha version out to our test team.

Comment: to see google play as shown in the above screenshots, I had to switch to google play classic view (discontinued from Nov 2nd 2020). Not sure where to find it in the new view though :(

Answer (score 4):

When you create an internal test, you release your app immediately to your internal testers. This can help you identify issues and receive feedback earlier in your development process. An internal test is:

**Fast:** You can distribute apps via the internal test track much faster than the open or closed tracks. When you publish a new APK or app bundle to the internal test track, it will be available to testers within a few minutes.

Note: **If you're publishing an app for the first time, it may take up to 48 hours for your app's internal test to be available.**

**Flexible:** An internal test can be adjusted to support different testing stages, including internal testing, quality assurance checks, and post-launch debugging.
Safe: With the internal test track, your test app is distributed to users via the Play Store.

Comment: The 48 hours thing is a killer. Testflight has no such problem. 2 days waiting for test team is an eternity to wait when on a tight release schedule.

Comment: spartygw, you could distribute an apk to them manually, or if they are developers and they build the project directly on their machine they can build directly to a device.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check that you've completed all the required steps for publication! On the left sidebar of the Play Store for your app, check that there are no "!" icons; everything should have a green check-mark.