# Can I get opt-in URL with alpha?

Tags: android

First, I read this answer
[Where is the Opt-in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256603/where-is-the-opt-in-url)

I uploaded my app to play store internal test & alpha private test.

But opt-in URL is not available just say that

`An opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app.`

I am confuse about how can i get opt-in URL and test it.

My team doesn't want to publish app to play store yet. (Just want internal/alpha test with GMail or GSuite)

I published my alpha test just ago.

What is problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opt-URL will available when Google publish your application in Google Play, but not public. It may take 1 to 3 hours to visible.

In my experience, it came out in an hour and a half.

Comment: Then, can i get Opt-in URL with only alpha test? App state is showed "unpublished" yet

Comment: If you publish app in alpha track, Opt-in URL will available in alpha track only. If google marked application to 'published', Opt-in URL will available.

Comment: I can't understand "published" meaning. If there is an alpha or beta version without production publish then It will change "published"?? Now it is "Unpublished" yet

Comment: Unpublished means not published yet. if published, it will be 'Pending publication'. Check out your console page and **make sure publish in alpha channel** and wait for few hours to get Opt-in URL.

Comment: hi, I already wait for 20hour+ after upload app and console says its published, still opt in link does not appear. any thought about the reason?

Comment: Did you solved this? it is very frustrating that I don't know what I'm supposed to do here. I have a button that says "release to production" but I don't know if this will promote my alpha version straight to production (available for everyone) or it will just release my alpha to selected testers.

Comment: I wanted for 12+ hours and still unable to get Opt-in URL...  the app is in pending publication mode.. do i really have to release to production?

Comment: try release as alpha test